# Android Textview unable to display special characters?

Tags: android, android-webview, textview

I need to display data from sqlite with some special characters on it like for example,

myStr = "Testing123ʳ" (actual value is loaded from sqlite)

which contains a modifier letter small ʳ (U+02B3)

Refer to character info here
http://graphemica.com/%CA%B3

I have tried

```
 1. myTextv.setText(Html.fromHtml(myStr))

 2. myTextv.setText("\u02B3")

 3. myTextv.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#691;"))
```

All doesn't work...

Comment: Cant you use a superscript tag for that "r"?

Comment: There's other special characters too and the text is from database. More ever the special characters could be anywhere in the string not only at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with Hangul(Korean) characters. For me, my problem wasn't encoding the data I received from the server, but encoding the request I sent it.

I used [URLEncoder](http:///https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode my String into percent form:

```
 String word = URLEncoder.encode(editText.getText().toString(),"UTF-8");
```

When I sent the request with this encoding, the response was correctly encoded.

If that doesn't work, you could try the [URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) to decode the response. I recommend using a Unicode converter like [this](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter) one, then see what encoding the TextView is using.

Comment: 2 years older post i dont know user still active r not but am appreciated for your answer.

Comment: No problem. I figured it would help other people looking for a solution to this problem. If it helped you please give my answer an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you have given attribute `android:textAllCaps="true"` in `.xml` file, then special character not displayed even programmatically not works. Its better to change attribute to `android:textAllCaps="false"` or remove this attribute if not necessary from `.xml` file. Happy coding..